# Open cash-drawer which is connected to an epson printer from java

Tags: java, printing

I would like to open the cash drawer which is connected to my TM-H6000II reciept printer from java.

There are several ways I found:

1. Opening the drawer before or after printing (But I don't want to print always)
2. using a font named "control" (Font.getFont("control") returns null, but is visible from other applications
3. Sending the control sequence to open the cash drawer directly to the printer

However, I would prefer method 3 but I found no java api to send Text-Data to the printer. I found examples for command-line but my printer is connected via usb and these examples were for com-ports.

Is there a java api to send data directly to the printer, so that I can send the control sequence?

*(Tips for the other problems are welcome too. Using Java8, so JavaFX Solutions are welcome too.)*

I am also puzzeled how I should recieve that the drawer is opened, is there a way to recieve feedback from a printer?